# Spring JWT refresh token not taking the new expire time

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Having the following implementation

```
@Configuration
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuthConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

private final UserDetailsService userService;

@Value("${jwt.client.id}")
private String clientId;

@Value("${jwt.client.secret}")
private String clientSecret;

@Value("${jwt.token.accessValidititySeconds}") // 12 hours 43200
private int accessTokenValiditySeconds;

@Value("${jwt.token.refreshValiditySeconds}") // 30 days
private int refreshTokenValiditySeconds;

@Value("${jwt.authorizedGrantTypes:password,authorization_code,refresh_token}")
private String[] authorizedGrantTypes;

@Value("${jwt.signingKey}")
private String signingKey;

public OAuthConfiguration(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
        UserDetailsService userService) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    this.userService = userService;
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
      // @formatter:off 
    clients.inMemory()
      .withClient(clientId)
      .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(clientSecret))
      .authorizedGrantTypes(authorizedGrantTypes)
      .scopes("client", "read", "write", "trust")
      .autoApprove("client")
      .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(refreshTokenValiditySeconds)
      .accessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValiditySeconds) 
      .resourceIds("team");
      // @formatter:on
}

@Override
public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
    endpoints
        .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
        .userDetailsService(userService)
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .tokenStore(tokenStore());
}

@Bean
JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    converter.setSigningKey(signingKey);
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
}

@Bean
@Primary
public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
    final DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
    tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
    return tokenServices;
}
}
```

The auth flow is good, the refresh flow is good but the problem is that the `refresh_token` will come all the time with the same `expiration time` as the first token issued after login

So, supposing that

- I will login at 2:00
- the `auth_token` will be valid for 1 minute
- the `refresh_token` for 5 minutes

The `/oauth/token` request with `grant_type: refresh_token` and `refresh_token: value.here` payload succeed 4 times but the `refresh_token` will be valid until 2:05 all the time and at the 5th request I'll get `Handling error: InvalidTokenException, Invalid refresh token (expired)`

Form [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/xref/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultTokenServices.html#L173) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/xref/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultTokenServices.html#L286) I understand that the token will be valid from now + `refreshTokenValiditySeconds` after each `access_token` refresh

What am I missing?